# Horizontal LinearLayout with children ordered right-to-left?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout that's programmatically filled with its children. I would like to be able to switch to a right-to-left layout (i.e. child 0 is on the far right, child 1 to its left, etc.) . The thing is, I want the layout to switch from RtL to LtR and back dynamically, that's why e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461793/linearlayout-filled-from-right-to-left) is irrelevant to my case.

There doesn't seem to be any way to set it directly in the code, especially since gravity is for alignment, not ordering.

So far I see the following workarounds:

- **On the ordering switch, re-add the children in an inverted order** (problem: very ugly and resource-consuming).
- **Implement a subclass of *LinearLayout* with an overridden *onLayout()* method** (problem: lots of copy-pasting the Android source due to helper layout members having a restrictive visibility).
- **Replace the *LinearLayout* with another, e.g. a *TableLayout* or a *RelativeLayout*, and change the layout params of the children on switch** (problem: still somewhat kludgey).

Any more direct solutions or better workarounds?

**EDIT:** to clarify, I'm creating the children practically once during the activity run-time, and I can store them in a helper array/collection at no complication to the code.

Comment: you are adding child to layout one at a time or adding it all together with loop?

Comment: It's one loop, and I can store the references in a helper structure without much complication. I'll edit the question to clarify this point.

Comment: you can pass a second parameter as index, which might help in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58204423/5296352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While re-creating the children might be resource-intensive, re-ordering shouldn't be that bad. You can take the existing views using [`getChildAt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and [`getChildCount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) and then put them back in using the [`addView` override with an index](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29).

Comment: That's exactly what the first workaround mentioned is about. Looking at the source of the layouting methods, there's a lot of going on, but maybe I'm worrying too much. Still, I'll wait for other answers because I've asked the question on a hunch that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Do a LinearLayout.setRotationY(180). You will also have to set the Y rotation of the child views of the Linear Layout to 180 also. So for example:

```
private void horizontal() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    View childView1 = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.childView1);
    View childView2 = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.childView2);

    layout.setRotationY(180);
    childView1.setRotationY(180);
    childView2.setRotationY(180);
}
```

The code may be wrong, but you get the idea.