# Adding views in LinearLayout in reverse order

Tags: java, android-linearlayout

I am dynamically adding views to a linear layout. I want the view to be in reverse order. Like first I added RadioButton and then I added CheckBox so I want CheckBox on top then RadioButton. In simple newly added view should be shown on top. I'm not using Recycelerview nor I can.

**I have tried** `android:layoutDirection` but it only working from RTL or LTR.

This is how I'm adding them in linear layout

```java
CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams cardParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
cardParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
cardView.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
LinearLayout cardLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
cardLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

cardView.addView(cardLayout);
linearLayout.addView(cardView);

final EditText questionText = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);
questionText.setPadding(15, 10, 10, 10);
questionText.setText(title);

edtTags.add(questionText);
questionText.setTag(edtTags.size());
questionText.setLayoutParams(textParams);
cardLayout.addView(questionText);
```

Comment: You can use `layout.addView(yourView,index)`. The index is the position at which to add the child. So by changing the index, you can change the order of the views to be added.

Comment: Iam dynamically adding views and they can be from 1 to 1000.So how I change the positions

Comment: with `linearLayout.addView(cardView, 0);` you put cardView on beginning, instead end of `linearLayout`

Comment: yup thats worked,thanku

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView), you can specify an index as the second parameter, so the following would do what you want

```
linearLayout.addView(cardView, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you boss. You make my day. Thanks once again !!!